# Postfix with dovecot unable to deliver message

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I'm trying to setup a mail service on my server with [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin) and [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-debian-wheezy) articles.

After finishing configuration, i got working user accounts - its possible to successfully login on each account with Thunderbird, manage folders etc. I can send email from one account to another without error (at least on client side) - but they can not be delivered. In `mail.log` i have:

```
Aug 31 13:03:46 serwer postfix/virtual[3516]: 4DCB1E132A: to=<admin@example.com>, relay=virtual, delay=2117, delays=2117/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (delivery failed to mailbox /home/vmail/%d/%n/1: unable to create lock file /home/vmail/%d/%n/1.lock: No such file or directory)
```

Of course domain is different, just replaced it now to hide real one. As i was searching on web for solutions i noticed that in other similar log entries, path to maildir is full resolved, like:

```
/home/vmail/example.com/admin/1.lock
```

In my logs its still with `%d` and `%n` - is this a problem?

Postfix conf:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_mailbox_base=/home/vmail/%d/%n
virtual_mailbox_domains=mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps=mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps=mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-alias.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the `virtual_mailbox_base` parameter like [you're supposed to](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_base).

> A prefix that the virtual(8) delivery agent prepends to all pathname results from $virtual_mailbox_maps table lookups. This is a safety measure to ensure that an out of control map doesn't litter the file system with mailboxes.

This is only a safety measure and isn't designed to indicate where the email should be delivered. That is the job of [`virtual_mailbox_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_maps).

You should instead set it to `virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail` and have your MySQL query from `virtual_mailbox_maps` returning a relative path to the users's mailbox directory, like "domain.com/username" which would then become "/home/vmail/domain.com/username" once prepended with the `virtual_mailbox_base`.

Comment: PS: most tutorials out there are bullshit and merely copy/paste other (older) tutorials with no concerns for performance or security. Rather than wasting your time with them, why don't you read the official Postfix documentation ? Also, do you really need MySQL ? Unless you have 100 accounts or more, a text file would give better performance and lower your attack surface & complexity.

Comment: Well, 100 accounts definitely not, but 100 aliases? Sure, or even more. (like individual email address for each website where i have account, all pointing to single email account) Maybe its a good idea to keep accounts in a file, ill think about it.

Comment: @WombaT if you just need an alias like `username-*anything*@domain.com` you can set `recipient_delimiter = -` and the single alias `username` will work for any `username-***anything***@domain.com` address.